# Typing to remap some of the object's properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a method which remaps object's keys by a given map. For example:

```
> remapKeys({key1: "xxx", key2: "yyy"}, {key1: "newKey"})
{ newKey: 'xxx', key2: 'yyy' }
```

However, I'm running into an issue when I try to make this method return a strongly-typed object. My current attempts looks like this:

```js
type MappedKeys<T extends { [key: string]: any }, M extends { [K in keyof Partial<T>]: string }> =
  | Omit<T, keyof M>
  | { [P in keyof T & keyof M as M[P]]: T[P] };

function remapKeys<T extends { [key: string]: any }, M extends { [K in keyof Partial<T>]: string }>(
  obj: T,
  mappings: M,
): MappedKeys<T, M>;
```

The idea here is that we try to make a union of two types:

1. subset of original properties that are not specified in `mappings` object
2. new type created from the intersection of `obj` and `mappings` properties

This doesn't work, however, because for some reason the implicit type of the returned value is an object with keys of type `string`, not `'newKey' | 'key2'`.

[Link to TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATA0hEBnAPAFShAD2AgDskMoBvKAbQGt0AuKDYAJwEsSBzAXWbgkQUAL4AaWPiKlyVWiihcoDEAHsAZlAAKcNsA5wANrgB8-Fuy7dRJqAF4AUFCgAfKAHkAth2C4JKjVgTJ1c5Gi1FEmV0QLwAMmi1TRgoOAoYcN5zHEzRAG4HB3UAVxIAY31VKLYITwQ0TFwpYjIKanomC04ec0FhcUlCFtl2hSUAzR09A2McM2ZWbusREwAKENUAIwArZhwxELrEKwxmGAOASjOEZAbsfaCChzKq1igt7fsoGqO71eoVABGZgAcgI4JB-nQACZQSB4SDRBIAehgVAQSQIAB3BqIkQXJ4vEgYVSGCAAOkMqm4qw+5MxOPQBIcQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an intersection (`&`), not a union (`|`):

```
type MappedKeys<T extends { [key: string]: any }, M extends { [K in keyof Partial<T>]: string }> =
  (Omit<T, keyof M> & { [P in keyof T & keyof M as M[P]]: T[P] }) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

Also, for extra flair, I have added `extends infer O ? ...` to simplify the type so you don't get the ugly `Omit<...> & { ... }` in tooltips. It'll always be a simple object now (`{ ... }`).

Here's the function now:

```
declare function remapKeys<T extends { [key: string]: any }, M extends { [K in keyof Partial<T>]: string }>(
  obj: Narrow<T>,
  mappings: Narrow<M>,
): MappedKeys<T, M>;
```

I've used this `Narrow` utility type so we don't need to use `as const`:

```
type Narrow<T> =
    | (T extends infer U ? U : never)
    | Extract<T, number | string | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined | []>
    | ([T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Narrow<T[K]> });
```

Otherwise, the second parameter will get inferred as `{ key1: string }` and then we can't remap keys.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ5a5m)